# How to display something when a user select a date?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to display something when a user select a date.This is my sample html code.but this isn't work.

```
<head>
<script>
document.getElementById("dateInput").select()=function(){whatsTheDay};
function whatsTheDay(){
document.getElementById("err").innerHTML="you enter a date";}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form>
<input type="date" id "dateInput" name = "brthdate"  />
<input type="submit" id = "submit"  name = "submitdt" onclick="sumitable"/>
</form>
<p id = "err"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Display *something*? What *someting*? An alertbox? seems you are trying to use `innerHTML`. Please describe your problem more detailed

Comment: Move your javascript to after you create the HTML elements they're calling, or use jQuery. You're calling `#dateInput` before it's created

Comment: plz look at my code. I want t display a message on paragraph (id="dateInput") @firelynx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<head>
<script>
document.getElementById("dateInput").select()=function(){whatsTheDay};
function whatsTheDay(){
document.getElementById("err").innerHTML="you enter a date";}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form>
<input type="date" id "dateInput" onchange="whatsTheDay()" name = "brthdate"  />
<input type="submit" id = "submit"  name = "submitdt" onclick="sumitable"/>
</form>
<p id = "err"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, this is work but look at this [link](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_onselect_dom). They are not using onchange or onselect event in <input>tag why? @Vishnu

Comment: They're using `onselect` in the JS.